# VIM: How to switch "errorfmt" between gcc4.1.2 and intel cpp compiler?

Tags: gcc, vim

In .vimrc I set errorformat to intel cpp format(suppose it's %f %l--%m), but sometimes, I need gcc error format, Is there a way to switch between this without editing .vimrc or type long commands?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not expected/supposed to change the error format manually in these two cases. Indeed, Vim provides the `:compiler` command that loads a script (in `{rtp}/compiler/`) that sets `'efm'` (and sometimes `&makeprg` as well).

In IOW:

- Execute `compiler icc` to interpret Intel C++ compiler outputs
- and execute `compiler gcc` to switch back to g++/clang++.